# Is there LC_COLLATE that sorts dot before dash?

Tags: zsh, wildcards, sort, locale

In the locales that I've checked (`C`, `en_US.UTF-8`) dot (".") is sorted after dash ("-"). When I `cd` and complete directory say "som", then `some-dir.git` is completed before `some.git`. I also list themes for my project and file `zdharma-256.theme` is globbed before `zdharma.theme`. A natural order for me is that the shorter directory is completed first.

Is there a `LC_COLLATE` that I could use to fix this?

Maybe it's not a collate problem, but problem of ignoring extension in first pass of sorting? Is there `Zsh` code (globbing flags, etc.) that I could use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such collate, at least not a standard one.

Here is how you can check it yourself:

1. first prepare a file (lines `Aa` and `aa` are here just for the test purpose)

   ```
   cat >test <<\eof
   Aa
   aa
   some.git
   some-dir.git
   eof
   ```
2. run the `sort` command with all possible collation available on the system:

   ```
   for loc in $(locale -a); do
       echo "____${loc}____";
       LC_COLLATE="$loc" sort test;
   done > test_sorted
   ```
3. now open `test_sorted` with your favorite editor and see that different locales sorted `Aa` and `aa` differently, but all of them have `some-dir.git` before `some.git`. In other words

   ```
   pcregrep -M 'some.git\nsome' test_sorted
   ```

   gives nothing.

The reason why `-` comes before `.` originates from ascii and unicode table (see `man ascii`). The hyphen character (technically it is called hyphen-minus sign) has the 45 decimal code (U+002D), while a dot is 46 (U+002E).

If you are desperate enough you can write your own locale, changing that behavior. The easiest is to modify one of the current files, which you can find in `/usr/share/i18n/locales/`.